# What is a .darc file and how to decompile?

Tags: android, apk, apktool, luac

I have decompiled a free android apk  with apktool and I found a file with .darc extension.
It has a lot of size and when I open it with and hex editor contain .luac files references and others but the luac files is not in the decompiled app folder. 
What can i do? Some idea?

The principal purpose of this question was to know how can i change some text in the apk. For example, customize the name of a village in the game or name of some tool.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Nobody can help you if you don't tell us what you want to do.

Comment: I want to change some text in the apk. But in the apk .xml files there isn't strings for change so the file .darc may be the clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a packaged archive: [see here](http://3dbrew.org/wiki/DARC) or here [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Darc/1.0) (a python package)

> Darc is an archiving system for use in media projects that allows
>   developers to contain and use their data files from .darc files that
>   store data in a bz2 compressed and AES encrypted (optional) format.

**UPDATE:**
you can try to uinpack the .darc file  using this utility (python):

[DARCTool](https://github.com/LITTOMA/DARCTool)

Comment: Yes the second link is the best answer. It have images file path, and luac files path.
Can I unpack this file?

Comment: Seems to be encrypted, this is the real problem

Comment: Ohhh, Thanks and kisses for try to help me

Comment: @tatyana I updated the answer

Comment: thanks! I found that tool in a forum, but the output is:
"game.darc" is not a darc file
I ran the command, in linux shell:
 python darc.py -u game.darc

Comment: If darc package is compressed with bz2 (but not encrypted), you might be able to unpack it with any tool that support bz2 (Ark etc). Anyway, can you tell me the app name so I can give it a look?

Comment: @Luca D'Amico Thanks for your interest, is only an android game I don't give it more time I investigate other things. Kiss

Comment: do we have any utility for Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Darc allows data files for media projects (images, sounds, videos etc.) to be stored in special container files called a .darc which compresses, encrypts, hashes, and then stores each file for verification and use at a later date.